# Effective DD/MM/YY - Does it include the date or not?

Tags: meaning

> End of Service for Photo Printer **effective January 31st, 2019**

In this sentence, does "effective January 31st, 2019" mean that the service won't be available **after January 31st**(which means that users can use the service on January 31st, but can't do that on February 1st) or **after January 30th**?

Comment: related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/417998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a gray area, but strictly speaking, "will end effective on such-and-such date" would mean that the matter in question *will have ended* on that date. In other words, the service will ***no longer be in effect*** starting on that date. Hurry up and come *before* that date.